# Code completion in Eclipse

Tags: apex, eclipse

I am new to Salesforce development. As part of setting up the environment, I have installed the Force.com IDE plugin in Eclipse Neon (4.6.2). After the installation of the plugin, I can create the slaseforce application and deploy the same in server and see the changes. But the content assist or code completion is not working. Someone has suggested to use [Apex LS Editor plugin](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/53564/42090). Its not working after the Apex plugin installation. I also do not see any option under Window-->Preferences.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Note: Location of the [Apex plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/apex-editor-ls)

Comment: Since you are new, dump eclipse and try illuminated cloud with IntelliJ. It will be the best move you made today

Comment: @Eric, My company does not have IntelliJ license. So its better to go for Eclipse.

Comment: Not better in any way, just your only choice. But for $60 or whatever it is, it is well worth it for the plugin and IntelliJ Community is free. In the end its your choice, unless your company forces you to use Eclipse,  of course, I can only recommend....